# Columns not displaying in columns tab (MySQL Workbench)

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

[image: Columns not displaying in "Columns" tab]

I am running Ubuntu 14.10 and MySQL Workbench v6.2.3-1ubu1404-amd64 (it`s last stable) and I am having issue with columns not displaying correctly (completely) - just blank space instead.

Is anybody experiencing the same problem? How to solve this?

Also experiencing issue in opensuse 13.2.  It worked in opensuse 13.1.

Comment: already tried updating all packages, rebooting, reinstalling mysql-workbench

Comment: possible duplicate of [The EER diagram editor is not displaying column data and other information](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26902391/the-eer-diagram-editor-is-not-displaying-column-data-and-other-information)

Comment: A couple weeks ago I submitted a debdiff based on the upstream glib patch and got it into the Ubuntu SRU process. Over the past few days it has made it into Ubuntu-proposed repository and appears many people have had success with it. More information can be found in this bug report: bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-workbench/+bug/1376154

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm the behavior you are seeing. It doesn't work on Ubuntu 14.10 and works On Ubuntu 14.04. I use `mysql-workbench` on Debian Wheezy with the expected behavior. So your question caught my attention because it appeared to be a bug.

I ran it from the command line to see what was on the console. When using the *EER Diagram Editor* with a sample model I was greeted with a blank pane where columns and their attributes should be listed. The console shows these unexpected assertions:

> (mysql-workbench-bin:52041): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (GtkTreeDragDest) to class (gtkmm__CustomObject_16ListModelWrapper) after class_init
>
> (mysql-workbench-bin:52041): GLib-GObject-WARNING **: attempting to add an interface (GtkTreeDragSource) to class (gtkmm__CustomObject_16ListModelWrapper) after class_init
>
> (mysql-workbench-bin:52041): Gtk-CRITICAL **: IA__gtk_tree_view_set_model: assertion 'model == NULL || GTK_IS_TREE_MODEL (model)' failed

There were far more errors but I have cut the list short. These assertions suggest to me that there is a bug while creating the window pane where the column data. It isn't just the column data where this happens but on a majority of the panes at the bottom.

I work on an open source project that also had issues with Ubuntu 14.10 and it also involved Glib assertions appearing where they didn't occur before. The Glib developers have begun adding more assertions to their code to identify software bugs. It is possible that something similar applies here. In the case of the project I maintain the assertions were indicative of a problem in our project code and the newer versions of Glib made our code fail.

With that in mind I looked on the Ubuntu launchpad site. There is this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mysql-workbench/+bug/1155571) with the title `Workbench not showing tables or query results in raring` that was opened last year but people are now identifying the issue with 14.10 as well (many in the past week). I believe it is related to what you are seeing. I also observed there are nearly 3 dozen people at this time that have reported a problem. You could create an account and add yourself to the list of people experiencing a problem.

There is good news and bad news. The MySQL workbench developers have [identified and fixed](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=74147) the problem in their latest builds. The MySQL bug report link has this to say:

> Posted by developer:
>
> Fixed as of the upcoming MySQL Workbench 6.2.4 release, and here's the changelog entry:
>
> On Linux, the query result view did not populate with libglib version 2.42
>   and above.

Unfortunately Ubuntu doesn't have a patch or work around in their official repositories *yet*. I think you have a few options:

- Don't use mysql-workbench on Ubuntu 14.10 until the bug is fixed and a new version of mysql-workbench is released by Ubuntu.
- Use an older version of Ubuntu (like 14.04) where it does work because it uses an older version of GLib
- Download the source and build your own version of MySQL Workbench 6.2.4 or later (This source hasn't officially been released yet)

Comment: i have 6.3.4 and still this issue... reinstall solved it.

Comment: lol, same problem, forgot the solution, my own comment saved me =)

Answer (score 1):

This is a known problem on Ubuntu 14.10 (there's a behavior change in glib). This bug has been fixed and the fix will be available in the next release. You can see this also in resultsets (blank results, even though a table has records).

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, follow the below steps :

```
  1. On the left hand side select "Table Tool".
  2. Click the canvas, which creates a default table.
  3. Select the table, right click it and select "Edit".
  4. Select the "Columns" tab on the bottom.
  5. Double click the "column name" text box and enter a column name.
  6. Click "Apply Changes".. You should see the column in the table now.
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. But the problem is that I don`t see anything in "Columns" tab, even in "Edit" mode.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens to me also and i just double click another table and when i double click back the table with the problem the columns are displayed.

If after re-installing the packages you have the same problem, try removing the table figure from the diagram and drag it back again from the catalog tree. Not sure if it helps at all...